# C: core dump when I try to pass my struct into a queue

Tags: c, pointers, struct, queue

**EDIT:** Creating and storing it into a temp node actually works...but I didn't dynamically allocate space for the new node...

```
struct node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Instead of

```
struct node *tempNode;
```

So I'm creating a queue to store a bunch of "connections" for a assignment.

I create the connection (which is a struct) fine, pass it into the enqueue function, it checks if its empty  (aka the first pointer in the queue is NULL) if it is then it suppose to store the connection into the first pointer node (which is a struct).

However, when it tries to put the incomingConnection into the node's connectionData, it core dumps. (If you're following my trail of printfs, it goes to PART 1 in enqueue and stops.). So it leads me to think something is wrong with the first part of my enqueueConnection function.

I tried making connection a void pointer in node, storing the connection into a temp node and then storing the temp node into the first node pointer of the queue...but neither worked.

Here is the function that the core dump is in...

```
int enqueueConnection(Queue *connectionQueue, Connection *incomingConnection)
{
    /*
    If the connection is empty
    */
    printf("CHECKING IF EMPTY\n");
    if(connectionQueue->first==NULL)
    {
        printf("PART 1 \n");
        connectionQueue->first->connectionData = incomingConnection; //FAILS HERE
        printf("PART 2\n");
        connectionQueue->first->next = connectionQueue->last; //which is NULL but
        printf("PART 3\n");
        connectionQueue->first->previous = NULL;
        printf("RETURNING\n");
        return NULL;
    }
....
```

Here is the rest of my code

queue.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct connections
{
    /*
    IP Address can be stored in two formats, IPv4 or IPv6. 
    IPv4 is 15 chars long and of the format ###.###.###.### in regular digits
    IPv6 is 25 chars long and of the format ####:####:####::####:### in hex
    */
    char* ipAddress[26];
    int port; //port value from 0-65535
    char* protocolType[2];
    union
    {
        char* connectionName[6]; //UDP only, 5 letter name to the connection
        int hops; //TCP only, 0-255 declaring the number of hops for the connection.
    }protocol;  
} Connection;

struct node
{
    Connection *connectionData;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *previous;
};

typedef struct queue
{
    struct node *first;
    struct node *last;
}Queue;

/*
Sets up new node in a temporary node, and then links the new node
with the previous last node, inserts connection data, declares next
node as null as this node will be the last. Then declares the last
node in the queue as the new node, as by defintion of a queue.
Also checks to make sure the queue does not have only 1 item in it or
if the queue is empty.
*/
int enqueueConnection(Queue *connectionQueue, Connection *incomingConnection)
{
    /*
    If the connection is empty
    */
    printf("CHECKING IF EMPTY\n");
    if(connectionQueue->first==NULL)
    {
        printf("PART 1 \n");
        connectionQueue->first->connectionData = incomingConnection;
        printf("PART 2\n");
        connectionQueue->first->next = connectionQueue->last; //which is NULL but
        printf("PART 3\n");
        connectionQueue->first->previous = NULL;
        printf("RETURNING\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    /*
    If the connection only has 1 item in it
    */
    if(connectionQueue->last==NULL)
    {
        connectionQueue->last->previous = connectionQueue->first;
        connectionQueue->last->connectionData = incomingConnection;
        connectionQueue->last->next = NULL;
        return NULL;
    }

    /*
    Sets up new node in a temporary node, and then links the new node
    with the previous last node, inserts connection data, declares next
    node as null as this node will be the last. Then declares the last
    node in the queue as the new node, as by defintion of a queue
    */
    struct node *tmp;

    tmp->previous = connectionQueue->last;
    tmp->connectionData=incomingConnection;
    tmp->next=NULL;
    connectionQueue->last=tmp;
    return NULL;
}

char* dequeueConnection(Queue *connectionQueue, Connection *incomingConnection)
{
    if(connectionQueue->first==NULL)
    {
        return "Error: Connection queue empty";
    }

    struct node *tmp, *tmp2, *tmp3;
    if(connectionQueue->last == NULL)
    {
        tmp = connectionQueue->first;
        connectionQueue->first = NULL;
        free(tmp);
        return NULL;
    }

    tmp = connectionQueue->first->next;
    while(tmp->connectionData != incomingConnection)
    {
        if(tmp == NULL)
        {
            return "Error: Connection not found";
        }

        tmp2 = tmp->next;
        tmp = tmp2;
    }

    tmp2 = tmp->next;
    tmp3 = tmp->previous;
    free(tmp);
    tmp2->previous = tmp3->next;
    return NULL;
}

int emptyQueue(Queue *connectionQueue)
{
    if(connectionQueue->first == NULL)
    {
        if(connectionQueue->last == NULL)
        {
            free(connectionQueue);
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    struct node *tmp;
    while(connectionQueue->first != NULL)
    {
        tmp = connectionQueue->first;
        connectionQueue->first = tmp->next;
        connectionQueue->first->previous = NULL;
        tmp->previous=NULL;
        tmp->next=NULL;
        free(tmp);
    }

    connectionQueue->last=NULL;
    return NULL;
}

Queue *createConnectionQueue()
{
    Queue *connectionQueue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    connectionQueue->first = NULL;
    connectionQueue->last = NULL;

    return connectionQueue;
}
```

networkManager2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "queue.h"

Connection *processConnection()
{
    /*
    Where the information for the connection is input.
    Connection is stored and created on the heap
    */
    Connection *currentConnection = malloc(sizeof(Connection));
    printf("IP Address: ");
    gets(currentConnection->ipAddress);
    printf("Protocol Type: ");
    gets(currentConnection->protocolType);
    printf("Port: ");
    scanf(" %d", &currentConnection->port);

    /*
    Depending on the protocol type, it stores hops or connection name.
    */
    if(strcmp(currentConnection->protocolType, "TCP") == 0)
    {
        printf("Hops: ");
        scanf(" %d", &currentConnection->protocol.hops);
    }
    else if(strcmp(currentConnection->protocolType, "UDP") == 0)
    {
        printf("Connection Name: ");
        scanf(" %s",&currentConnection->protocol.connectionName);
    }

    return currentConnection;
}

void storeConnection(Queue *connectionQueue, Connection *incomingConnection)
{
    printf("IN STORE CONNECTION\n");
    enqueueConnection(connectionQueue,incomingConnection);
    printf("%s and %s",connectionQueue->first->connectionData->ipAddress,connectionQueue->first->connectionData->ipAddress);
}

int main()
{
    int running = 0; //variable to check if the user wants to input more connections
    char* holder[1];

    printf("STARTED\n");
    Queue *connectionQueue = createConnectionQueue();
    printf("QUEUE CREATED\n");

    /*
    Inputs connections and stores them in an array of connections. The array can
    only hold up to 5 connections and replaces the oldest each time if its full. 
    */
    do
    {
        Connection *incomingConnection = processConnection();
        printf("CONNECTION MADE\n");
        storeConnection(connectionQueue,incomingConnection);
        printf("Continue?: ");
        scanf(" %d",&running);
        gets(holder); //avoid the scanf problem.
    }while(running == 0);
    emptyQueue(connectionQueue);
    printf("Deleted");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

All your problems are from your structure attributes type :

```
char* ipAddress[26];
```

Here, I supposed you wanted to make a 26-bytes long char array. But you declared a 26-pointers long char char array. An array should look like this :

```
char* ipAddress;
```

If you want to allocate it dynamicly (using [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) for instance) or :

```
char ipAddress[26];
```

If you want to have a pre-allocated size in stack when you declare it. I suppose that is the case that you want in your case.

And for gets it, pass the pointer of the array :

```
gets(&currentConnection->ipAddress);
```

Comment: Didn't see that, thanks. However I'm still getting the same core dump at the same spot. I did change all the strings now to for example char ipAddress[26]; and gets(&currentConnection->ipAddress); and as far as I can see connection holds it since printf("%s", incomingConnection->ipAddress); works after I create the connection

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it using a temp node...I just didn't dynamically allocate the new node when I first tried it. Thanks for your help though, you prob saved me more problems down the line  :).

Answer (score 1):

I bet it does fail.  You're explicitly dereferencing a pointer **you just checked and found to be NULL.**

```
if(connectionQueue->first==NULL)
{
    printf("PART 1 \n");
    connectionQueue->first->connectionData = incomingConnection; //FAILS HERE
```

And use `fprintf( stderr, ... )` instead of `printf(...)`.  `printf()` is buffered so you may not see output before things crash.